# onPreviewFrame YUV grayscale skewed

Tags: android, image, computer-vision, yuv

I'm trying to get the picture from a surfaceView where I have the camera view running,

I've already implemented onPreviewFrame, and it's called correctly as the debug shows me.

The problem I'm facing now, it's since the byte[] data I receive in the method, it's in YUV space color (NV21), I'm trying to convert it to grayscale to generate a Bitmap and then storing it into a file.

The conversion process that I'm following it's:

```
 public Bitmap convertYuvGrayScaleRGB(byte[] yuv, int width, int height) {

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

    for (int i = 0; i < height*width; i++) {
        int grey = yuv[i] & 0xff;
        pixels[i] = 0xFF000000 | (grey * 0x00010101);
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  }
```

The importing procedure for storing it to a file, it's:

```
Bitmap bitmap = convertYuvGrayScaleRGB(data,widht,heigth);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bytes);

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator + "test.jpg");

    Log.d("Camera", "File: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
         } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Altough, the result I've got it's the following:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any obvious mistake in your code, but i've already met this kind of skewed images before. When this happened to me, it was due to:

- At some point in the code, the image width and height are swapped,
- Or the original image you're trying to convert has padding, in which case you will need a `stride` in addition of the width and height.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Width of the image you are converting is not even. in that case 
it is padded in memory.

Let me have a look at the docs...

It seems more complicated than this. if you want your code to work as it is now, you will have to have the width
a multiple of 16.

from the docs:

> public static final int YV12
>
> Added in API level 9 Android YUV format.
>
> This format is exposed to software decoders and applications.
>
> YV12 is a 4:2:0 YCrCb planar format comprised of a WxH Y plane
>   followed by (W/2) x (H/2) Cr and Cb planes.
>
> This format assumes
>
> an even width an even height a horizontal stride multiple of 16 pixels
>   a vertical stride equal to the height  y_size = stride * height 
>   c_stride = ALIGN(stride/2, 16)  c_size = c_stride * height/2  size =
>   y_size + c_size * 2  cr_offset = y_size  cb_offset = y_size + c_size

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with the S3. My problem was that I used the wrong dimensions for the preview. I assumed the camera was 16:9 when it was actually 4:3.

Use Camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize() to see what the output is in.

Answer (score 0):

I made this:

```
int frameSize = width * height;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        ret[frameSize + (i >> 1) * width + (j & ~1) + 1] = 127; //U
        ret[frameSize + (i >> 1) * width + (j & ~1) + 0] = 127; //V
    }
}
```

So simple but it works really good and fast ;)